# how does std::vector deal with the call to destructor?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, std

When tring to implement `std::vector`, I get confused with the implicit call to destructor.

Then element in vector maybe:

- `T`

  - a Class Object,
- `T*`,  `shared_ptr<T>`

  - a Smart/Simple Pointer to Class Object
- `int`

  - built-in type
- `int *`

  - pointer to  built-in type

When calling `resize()`,`reserve()` ,`erase()`or `pop_back()`, the destructor might be called.

**I wonder how does `std::vector` deal with the call to destructor.**

I found, only when the type is a build-in pointer won't `std::vector` call the destructor(Of course if it have one).

**Does `std::vector` implement it by distinguishing type and determine whether or not to call the destructor?**

Below are some experiments about the question:

**Example 1**, the element is Object.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Tmp {
    ~Tmp() { cerr << "Destructor is called." << endl; }
};

int main (void)
{
    std::vector<Tmp>arr;
    Tmp tmp = Tmp();
    cerr << "Capacity:" << arr.capacity() << endl;//0
    arr.push_back (tmp);
    cerr << "Capacity:" << arr.capacity() << endl;//1
    arr.push_back (tmp);
    cerr << "Capacity:" << arr.capacity() << endl;//2
    cerr << "popback start------------" << std::endl;
    arr.pop_back();
    arr.pop_back();
    cerr << "popback end--------------" << endl;
}
```

the output is:

```bash
Capacity:0
Capacity:1
Destructor is called.
Capacity:2
popback start------------
Destructor is called.
Destructor is called.
popback end--------------
Destructor is called.
```

**Example 2**, the element is builtin-in pointer to obecjt:

```cpp
...
std::vector<Tmp>arr;
Tmp * tmp = new Tmp;
...
```

The destructor won't be called automatically:

```bash
Capacity:0
Capacity:1
Capacity:2
popback start------------
popback end--------------
```

**Example 3**, shared_ptr

```cpp
std::vector<shared_ptr<Tmp>>arr;
auto tmp = make_shared<Tmp>();

... //after being copied, the references count should be 3.
tmp = nullptr; //References count reduced by 1

cerr << "popback start------------" << std::endl;
arr.pop_back();//References count reduced by 1
arr.pop_back();//References count reduced by 1
cerr << "popback end--------------" << endl;
```

The destructor of shared_ptr will be called. When the references reduced to 0, the destructor of Tmp will be called:

```bash
Capacity:0
Capacity:1
Capacity:2
popback start------------
Destructor is called.
popback end--------------
```

Comment: Why do you print the capacity instead of the size? The capacity represents the amount of memory allocated for the vector, but some of that memory might not be initialized and not contain any objects.

Comment: Your issue is that of conflating a pointer and the object it points to. They are different objects, and can be "destructed" independently.

Comment: I think the size is visible to the naked eye while the capacity is not.

Comment: The difference is that the size is the number of actual constructed objects inside the vector, while the capacity is not. You can have a capacity of `6` with a size of only `4`. That means there are only `4` actual, constructed object inside the vector. Then there's *uninitialized* memory for `2` more objects, but there aren't more objects, so nothing in those two slots can be destructed.

Comment: "When tring to implement std::vector," do you actually mean you want to use `std::vector` ?

Answer (score 3):

The destructor of `int*` does nothing.  The destructor of `T*` does nothing.

You might think "destroy an int pointer" means to call `delete ptr`, but that isn't destroying the pointer.  That is destroying what the pointer points to, and recycling the memory allocated for it (which is 2 distinct steps).

So a `vector<int*>` destroys all of the `int*`s in it; that destruction is, however, a noop.

The destructor of `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` also destroys all of the `shared_ptr<T>` within it; that destructor decrements a reference count, and if it hits zero destroys the `T`.

Same thing for `vector<T>` and `vector<T*>` -- in both cases, the destructor is (logically) run, but the destructor of `T*` is a noop, while the destructor of `T` is `T::~T()`.

---

In C++, every instance is an object.  An `int` is an object, a `int*` is an object, a `vector<int>` is an object, and `struct Foo{}; Foo foo;` is an object.

Destroying an object is sometimes a noop.  This is true of all primitive types, *including* pointers.

Because it is a noop, people get sloppy and talk about destroying a pointer the same as if they talk about destroying what is pointed to by the pointer.  But they aren't the same thing.

```
struct Noisy {
  ~Noisy() { std::cout << "~Noisy\n"; }
};
using Ptr = Noisy*;
```

I can do this:

```
Ptr ptr;
ptr.~Ptr(); // compilers might complain here in non-generic code
```

and that is a noop; here I am attempting to manually call the (pseudo) destructor of `ptr`, which is a pointer.  This (pseudo) destructor is a noop, so no code is run.

```
Ptr ptr = new Noisy();
delete ptr;
```

this actually destroys `*ptr`, not `ptr`.  It then recycles the memory we used to store `*ptr`.

`new Noisy()` also does two things -- it gets memory to store a `Noisy` from the "free store", and then it constructs that object in the memory it got.

You can split these operations up.  You can allocate the storage separately from creating the object (this is called placement new), and you can destroy the object separately from recycling the storage.

Doing so is considered an advanced technique in C++, which is why nobody talks to you about it.

```
void demo() {
  alignas(Noisy) char buffer[sizeof(Noisy)];
  Noisy* ptr = ::new( (void*)buffer ) Noisy();
  ptr->~Noisy();
}
```

this makes a buffer on the stack (not automatic storage), manually constructs a `Noisy` object in it, then manually destroys the `Noisy` object.

```
template<class T>
void demo2() {
  alignas(T) char buffer[sizeof(T)];
  T* ptr = ::new( (void*)buffer ) T();
  ptr->~T();
}
```

this makes the demo generic.  I can do `demo<int>()` or `demo<Noisy>()` and demonstrate construction/destruction separate from storage.

`std::vector` is doing something like this -- it manages a buffer of storage (measured by `vec.capacity()`) and a bunch of objects "at the front" of that buffer (measured by `vec.size()`).  And it manually constructs and destroys the objects within its buffer using techniques similar to `demo2`.

And destroying a raw pointer doesn't cause the pointed-to object to be destroyed.  But the same isn't true of an instance or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have the pointer defined by:

```
Tmp * tmp = new Tmp;
```

This can be illustrated like this:

```
+--------------+      +------------+
| variable tmp | ---> | Tmp object |
+--------------+      +------------+
```

When you have a vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<Tmp*> vec;
```

and add a pointer:

```
vec.push_back(tmp);
```

then you have something like this:

```
+--------------+
| variable tmp | --\
+--------------+   |     +------------+
                    >--> | Tmp object |
+--------+         |     +------------+
| vec[0] | --------/
+--------+
```

From these illustrations it can easily be seen that the vector doesn't contain the `Tmp` object itself, only a pointer to it.

Therefore when you remove the pointer from the vector

```
vec.pop_back();
```

only the pointer inside the vector is removed and destructed. The `Tmp` object itself still lives on, and we once again have the first illustration.

Comment: I know what you mean. I wonder how to implement the step "remove".It seems troublesome to check the type and determine whether or not to call the destructor.

Comment: You don't need to check, you always call the destructor. Asm for ~T(), where T is trivial simply gives noop.

Comment: @sixsixqaq All objects inside a vector are managed by the vector itself. It handles the life-time of all its stored objects. You shouldn't "call the destructor" on objects inside a vector. Or generally on *any* object (unless you have used placement new to initialize an object).

Comment: @sixsixqaq If you have a vector of pointers to objects, and you don't have any other stored pointer to the objects, then you should **`delete`** objects before you remove the pointers from the vectors. Or use smart pointers where where life-time is managed.

Comment: Generally, C++ code (written by a C++ developer) does not need to work out when to call destructors.   All code needs to do is end the life of an object (e.g. the enclosing scope ends for an object of automatic storage duration, a `delete` expression for a dynamically allocated object, etc).   The compiler takes care of the mechanics of actually destroying the object - including calling destructors if necessary - since it has information (e.g. about the type of every object) to do so.  [except in some specialised cases - but those are exceptions].